# passing variable from apex report to javascript function

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I was looking over S.O. and found two questions that combined would solve a problem I am having.
I would like to post pct markers onto google map from Apex report.

passing variable from report works.. javascript:LOCATION(#LOCATION#);

but I can't seem to get the javascript to run.
thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LOCATION(pLoc){  
var Loc = (pLoc);
var locations = ['+Loc+'];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }}
  })(marker, i));
 }
}
</script>
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the value of pLoc? Have you tried to debug? Are you receiving javascript errors?

Comment: Hey Tom. No errors. pLoc is .. example... ['pct',30.12,-97.34,12]

Comment: also Tom, I use stragg to create array.

Comment: select stragg(a.location) as location, a.region
from
(SELECT DISTINCT rownum,  '['||''''||'test'||''''|| c.lon ||','|| c.lat ||', '||rownum|| ']'  as location, a.pct_name, b.election_code_id, c.region
FROM ecms.prv_pcts a,
  ecms.sites_assign b,
  ecms.sites_details c
WHERE b.site_id = c.site_id
AND b.pct_id    = a.prv_pct_id
AND a.pct_name NOT LIKE 'ALL PR%'
and b.election_code_id is not null
and b.election_code_id = '117'
ORDER by 1, 2) a
group by a.region

Comment: Okay - so that'll come out of the sql somehow: how do you provide this value to the page/javascript? I know you've put up an example op pLoc there, but is that the exact assigned value, ie have you checked with console.log or something or is that the value your sql should provide? To me it looks like variable locations has incorrect values, you are only assigning it an array with 1 value at index 0.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your response. I have worked on my javascript to be able to work with you comment.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your response. I ran a test to see my out put as you suggested. I change to SQL report to send Lat and Lon as serperate variables to the function. apex - javascript:myFunction(#LAT#,#LON#); The values passed and the output seem correct .. example : [30.97, -97.45].

Comment: <script>
function myFunction(a,b) { 
var fruits = [a,b];
var str = fruits.join(', ');
var root = ["[" +str+ "]"];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = root;
}
</script> . also I change LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]) to reflect only two variables... LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]).  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Tom, throw an answer out for this, I'll up vote you. :)  Robin, It would help the question if you added your `script` (above) to the body of your question, then future visitors would benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query:

```
SELECT stragg(a.location) as location, a.region 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT rownum
      , '['||''''||'test'||''''|| c.lon ||','|| c.lat ||', '||rownum|| ']' as location
      , a.pct_name
      , b.election_code_id
      , c.region 
  FROM ecms.prv_pcts a
     , ecms.sites_assign b
     , ecms.sites_details c 
 WHERE b.site_id = c.site_id 
   AND b.pct_id  = a.prv_pct_id 
   AND a.pct_name NOT LIKE 'ALL PR%' 
   AND b.election_code_id IS NOT NULL
   AND b.election_code_id = '117' 
 ORDER by 1, 2
) a 
GROUP BY a.region
```

Would give an output of:

```
['testLON',LAT,1],['testLON2',LAT2,2]
```

Calling function LOCATION with these values would provide the function with multiple parameters. 
Thus, `locations[][]` wouldn't exactly work as `pLoc` is not an array holding arrays. You could fix this by using

```
SELECT '['||stragg(a.location)||']' as location, a.region
```

Also,

- `var locations = ['+Loc+'];` kind of defeats the purpose, no?
- `DISTINCT ROWNUM`?

Comment: Tom, again thanks for your time. When i posted my question, i didn't ask the question correctly. I have spent a little time looking at javascript and i better understand what i am attempting to do, but still don't know how to do it...  Here is the correct questions.." How does one create a dynamic array from an apex report?"